# Pyspark- Take total sum of a column and use the value to divide another column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe `df`

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([[1,0], [2,1], [3,1], [4,0], [5,1]], ['a', 'b'])
>>> df.show()
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  0|
|  2|  1|
|  3|  1|
|  4|  0|
|  5|  1|
+---+---+
```

and

```
>>> nrows = df.count()
```

Using `df`, I created a new dataframe `a` that is an aggregate of `df`.

```
>>> a = df.groupby('b').count()
>>> a.show()
+---+-----+
|  b|count|
+---+-----+
|  0|    2|
|  1|    3|
+---+-----+
```

I need to create a new column in `a` called `ev`. The value of `ev` on the `i`th row is given by

[image]

This is the output I'm expecting

```
+---+-----+------------------+
|  b|count|           ev_norm|
+---+-----+------------------+
|  0|    2|              1.25|
|  1|    3|0.8333333333333334|
+---+-----+------------------+
```

But I reached here by first, creating a new column `num` for the numerator `(nrows-count)` which yields `3,2` on the two rows. I then proceeded to calculate the denominator (`denom=0.48`) which is the same for all rows. Lastly, I created a new column using `.withColumn` that divides the `num` column with `denom`.

Is there a way I can perform the calculation of `denom` on the fly without having to precalculate it and perform the above operations in a single step?

I tried something like

```
a = a.withColumn('ev_norm', (nrows - F.col('count'))/F.sum(F.col('count')*(nrows - F.col('count'))))`
```

and

```
a = a.withColumn('ev_norm', (sum([F.col('count')*(nrows-F.col('count'))]))
```

but it either gives me an error or the wrong answer.

Comment: You should notice that if you can do this computation on the fly, you will do it for each row and it has a high computational cost. Hence, it would be plausible to precompute this single value!

Comment: [Don't post pictures of code/data/formulas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).